# Setting Up OpenVPN Communication Error

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to my OpenVPN Server and I'm getting a timeout when connecting, I've tried through a Linux client and it times out with the log error:

```
root@XXXX:~# sudo openvpn --config /XXXX.ovpn
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018, LZO 2.10
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:1194
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Tue Mar 12 11:38:20 2019 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:1194 [nonblock]
Tue Mar 12 11:40:20 2019 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:1194 failed: Connection timed out
Tue Mar 12 11:40:20 2019 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Tue Mar 12 11:40:20 2019 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_ins
```

My OpenVPN server is behind a router and I have configured it so that the traffic coming from internet in port 1194, redirects to the internal IP  of the server. Besides science my ISP has a dinamic IP, I've set in my client conf a Dyndns name so that the client can connect to my router.

Comment: To see if you can reach the server at all, you can test the connection from the client by giving the command `echo -e "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | timeout 10 nc -u [address of your openvpn server] [port] | od -x -N 14`  If it's reachable, the server will echo back some hex packets like `0000000 7b40 fbec ddb6 db32 00e4 0000 0000
0000016`  If nothing bounces back, your server is not reachable.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks, the response was `000000`

Comment: Why do you use a TCP connection?

Comment: Because UDP didn't do the trick

Comment: Since you can reach the server, I suspect that your client and server options are not identical. I'd check that over carefully.

Comment: I do not see any diffrences, iwould post it but it's too long, the forum doesn't support it